# Convert List<Enum> into Seq[(String,String)]

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, scala-java-interop

I want to use [`@helper.select`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/select.scala.html) form Play 2 template engine where I should specify `Seq[(String,String)]` containing data for `<options>`. But I have `List<Enum>`. And I know rather weakly Scala.

Without this helper I populate `<select>` using this code:

```
@for( category <- Categories.values()){
   <option value="@category">@Messages.get( category.getI18NName )</option>
}
```

And definition of Category:

```
public enum Category{
    CATEGORY1{
        @Override
        public String getI18NName(){
            return "category.category1";
        }
    },
    CATEGORY2{
        @Override
        public String getI18NName(){
            return "category.category2";
        }
    };

    public String getI18NName(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

For test I used `options = options("1" -> "1", "2" -> "2", "3" -> "3", "4" -> "4", "5" -> "5")` form [Java example of inputRadioGroup in Play2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051711/java-example-of-inputradiogroup-in-play2)

How can I get `Seq[(String,String)]` from my `List<Enum>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for comprehension here:

```
for (c <- Category.values()) yield c.name() -> c.getI18NName()
```

This will return an `Array[(String, String)]` but scala will handle conversion when the expected type is `Seq[(String, String)]`.